# Exclude tags when searching and subscribing to tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

do you know if there is a way to do so, or can we request the following functionality:

- Ignore tags-in-tags.

What I mean by that, let's say I want to help people and browse knowledge in PHP, but I'm not interested in Wordpress or Laravel, so I can subscribe or view only those posts where PHP is tagged and not other.

What do you think about that? Can it be somehow implemented intuitively in the user interface of this site?

Comment: Did you mean like [`[php] -[wordpress] -[laravel]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+-wordpress+-laravel)? This can also be saved as a custom filter.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much :), didn't want to sound too stupid but seems like I do :). Thanks for the hint. I would interface it somehow if it was my project, but this community is for devs so maybe owners think people here are way too smart :)